# Angular dialog does not show message

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement [this](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#dialog-data) dialog box, i simply have to display a message depending on a the result of a condition.
The html for the dialog:

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
  Message:{{message}}
</div>
```

The code that opens the dialog:

```
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,)

updateDescription() {
    doSomething().subscribe(() => {
        this.openDialog(`Success`)
    }, error => {
        this.openDialog(`OOOPS ${error}`)
    }
    )

}


openDialog(message: String) {
    this.dialog.open(DialogUpdateMessage, {
        data:{
            message: message
        }
    })
}
```

The HTML that fires the event opens the dialog:

```
<textarea matInput style="resize: none;" rows="7">{{description}}</textarea>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-button-toggle (click)="updateDescription()">Update description</mat-button-toggle>
</form>
```

The ts class for the dialog component:

```
        @Component({
        selector: 'dialog-update-message',
        templateUrl: 'dialog-update-message.html',
    })
    export class DialogUpdateMessage {
        constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public message: String)

 { }
```

What i see when i perform the click is a dialog with `[object: Object]` in it, there is no message.
I think i am doing something wrong with the content of the `openDialog` function, somehow the `data` object is not rendered properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest changing the way you are sending the data to the dialog, instead of sending the data as an `object` send it as a `string` *(which looks to be your use-case)*.

```
openDialog(message: String) {
    this.dialog.open(DialogUpdateMessage, {
        data:{
            message: message
        }
    })
}
```

Instead, send a string here instead. If you are planning to send only a single property, if you are planning to send multiple properties then you'll have to create the object. But in your use case

```
openDialog(message: String) {
        this.dialog.open(DialogUpdateMessage, {
            data: message
        })
}
```

Now your code should work the same it was.

```
<div mat-dialog-content>
  Message:{{ message }}
</div>
```

and the property `message` will be typed as a `string` so, the method will make sure that you send a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

you are sending an object as data and you are trying to read it as string
try something like that

```
export class DialogUpdateMessage {
        constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any)

<div mat-dialog-content>
  Message:{{data.message}}
</div>
```